# How to download a GraphQL schema?

Tags: graphql, command-line-interface, schema, apollo, hasura

I am running an Apollo CLI command to obtain the schema from my Hasura endpoint.

```
apollo schema:download --header 'X-Hasura-Admin-Secret: <my secret>' --endpoint https://sample-backend-for-hasura-tutorial.hasura.app/v1/graphql schema.json
```

It fails with

```
  √ Loading Apollo Project
  × Saving schema to schema.json
    → TypeError:  is not a legal HTTP header name
    Error: TypeError:  is not a legal HTTP header name
```

I have tried various variations of the incantation, but all return the same error.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess would be to replace `'` with double quotations use something like

```
apollo schema:download --header="X-Hasura-Admin-Secret: <my secret>" --endpoint https://sample-backend-for-hasura-tutorial.hasura.app/v1/graphql schema.json
```

Comment: Thanks - that moved it on.
Now have a new problem, but probably best to raise it as a separate issue. It seems that there are multiple versions of the graphql libraries. Ho Hum. 
But thanks again

Comment: Deleted package-lock.json and npm_modules, and then ran npm install
Seems to have resolved the graphql version issue. I now have a schema - thanks.